# UPDATE STATISTICS returns an error "Table does not exist." in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, statistics

From below script, I have obtained the list of tables that need to be updated the statistics.

```
SELECT [sch].[name] + '.' + [so].[name] AS [TableName] ,
[ss].[name] AS [Statistic],
[sp].[last_updated] AS [StatsLastUpdated] ,
[sp].[rows] AS [RowsInTable] ,
[sp].[rows_sampled] AS [RowsSampled] ,
[sp].[modification_counter] AS [RowModifications]
FROM [sys].[stats] [ss]
JOIN [sys].[objects] [so] ON [ss].[object_id] = [so].[object_id]
JOIN [sys].[schemas] [sch] ON [so].[schema_id] = [sch].[schema_id]
OUTER APPLY [sys].[dm_db_stats_properties]([so].[object_id],
[ss].[stats_id]) sp
WHERE [so].[type] = 'U'
AND [sp].[modification_counter] > 0
```

The above query returns the table "dbo.LoginHistory" table as a result.

To perform the stat update I have executed below query.

```
UPDATE STATISTICS [dbo.LoginHistory] WITH FULLSCAN;
```

But it returns an error saying Table **'dbo.LoginHistory' does not exist.**

When I execute SELECT * FROM dbo.LoginHistory then it returns data (Which means the table exists).

Any idea why I see the error when running stats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove brackets [].
Use dbo.LoginHistory instead of [dbo.LoginHistory]

```
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.LoginHistory WITH FULLSCAN;
```

Comment: Yes. This is it :)